# Teleporting Character From Edge to Edge of the Screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to Teleport a character from a Edge of the screen to the contrary edge I'm using this:

```
var pos: Vector3 = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(transform.position);

       if (pos.x < 0.0) {
           pos = new Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
           transform.position = pos;
           //Debug.Log("I am left of the camera's view.");
       }


       if (1.0 < pos.x) {
           pos = new Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
           transform.position = pos;
          // Debug.Log("I am right of the camera's view.");
       } 
        if (pos.y < 0.0) Debug.Log("I am below the camera's view.");
        if (1.0 < pos.y) Debug.Log("I am above the camera's view.");
```

this work perfectly but the problem is that it teleport the character to the center and when I change the value to make it teleport to the edges it don't work correctly

Comment: its because the `pos` in the first line is "translated" into viewport space, but the position you set is in world space (and 0,0,0 is the center of the scene), you just need to "translate" the new coordinate in "the other direction", namely from viewport to world space.

Comment: @yes 
I know that is the center, what happen is that when I set the values to the edges It don't  work
What exactly should I chage?

Comment: Make use of `Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint` before you set the position https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportToWorldPoint.html

Comment: @yes So I must use ViewToWorldPoint instead of WorldToviewPoint

Comment: no, the position you **set** needs to be in world space.

Comment: @yes how I do that?

Comment: Alright, I'll wirte a full answer, gimme a few ...

Comment: @yes thank you very much bro✌✌

Comment: quick question, is it 2D using x, y as left-right, up-down respectively?

Comment: @yes is a 3D game but I using x and y and x reffer to left and right and y to up and down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you transform a world coordinate (`transform.position`) to viewport space, do some changes, but never transform back from viewport space to worldspace before you apply it to `transform.position`.

```
    //you get a world space coord and transfom it to viewport space.
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(transform.position);

    //everything from here on is in viewport space where 0,0 is the bottom 
    //left of your screen and 1,1 the top right.
    if (pos.x < 0.0f) {
        pos = new Vector3(1.0f, pos.y, pos.z);
    }
    else if (pos.x >= 1.0f) {
        pos = new Vector3(0.0f, pos.y, pos.z);
    }
    if (pos.y < 0.0f) {
        pos = new Vector3(pos.x, 1.0f, pos.z);
    }
    else if (pos.y >= 1.0f) {
        pos = new Vector3(pos.x, 0.0f, pos.z);
    }

    //and here it gets transformed back to world space.
    transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(pos);
```

Comment: I actually having a little trouble with the Y axis but apart from that the code is great thank you✌✌✌

Comment: @ShamuelSimpsonG. what trouble? Also if the answer helped, mark it as correct please.

Comment: Ready.  The character seems to float and goes down and up in the Y axis but only sometimes

Comment: @ShamuelSimpsonG. Hm, you'll need to describe that better I get no picture of what you mean :D